# Measuring actual bytes written through Java sockets

Tags: java, sockets, networking, progress-bar, outputstream

I have written a small program which send/receives files from one client to another. I've set up progressbars for both the receiver and the client, but the problem is that the sender seems to have his progressbar finish much quicker than the actual transfer. The problem lies with the how it calculates how many bytes that have been written. I'm assuming it's counting how many bytes I've read into buffer, rather than bytes that were sent through the network, so how can I find a solution to this problem? The receiver is calculating his received bytes at a correct rate, but the sender is not doing his part correctly.

Setting a lower buffersize offsets the difference a bit, but it's still not correct. I've tried wrapping the outputstream with a CountingOutputStream, but it returns the same result as the code snippet below. The transfer eventually completes correctly, but I need the proper "sent" values to update my progressbar, as in what was actually received and written to disc at the receiver side. I've included a very stripped down code snippet which represents my way of calculating transferred bytes. Any examples of a solution would be very helpful.

```
try
    {
    int sent = 0;
    Socket sk = new Socket(ip, port);
    OutputStream output = sk.getOutputStream();
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filepath);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8092];

    while ((bytesRead = file.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        sent += bytesRead;
        System.out.println(sent); // Shows incorrect values for the actual speed.
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could try calling flush() on the output stream right after the output.write() call, this will flush the buffers and actually cause the data to be send across the network.  However, buffers are there to increase performance and if you keep flush()ing performance might suffer.

Comment: @prunge flush() does *not* 'actually cause the data to be sent across the network', and in fact flush() on an undecorated socket output stream does nothing whatsoever.

Comment: @EJP you're right, looking at the source code shows that flush() does nothing.  I guess something to do to reduce latency could be to setTcpNoDelay(false) on the socket, which will turn off [Nagel's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).

Answer (score 4):

In short, I don't think you can get the sort of accurate visibility you're looking for solely from the "sender" side, given the number of buffers between you and the "wire" itself.  But also, I don't think that matters.  Here's why:

1. Bytes count as "sent" when they are handed to the network stack.  When you are sending a small number of bytes (such as your 8K example) those bytes are going to be buffered & the write() calls will return quickly.
2. Once you're reached network saturation, your write() calls will start to block as the various network buffers become full - and thus then you'll get a real sense of the timings.
3. If you really must have some sort of "how many bytes have you received?" you'll have to have the receiving end send that data back periodically via an out-of-band mechanism (such as suggested by glowcoder)

Answer (score 2):

Get the input stream from the socket, and on the other side, when you've written a selection of bytes to disk, write the result to the output stream. Spawn a second thread to handle the reading of this information, and link it to your counter.

Your variable is `sent` - it is accurate. What you need is a `received` or `processed` variable, and for that you will need two-way communication.